# Error Laravel log without any controller, class

Tags: laravel

I saw some log lines about AcessTokenMissMatch error, but I can not find what was wrong. Please help me to find down it.
This error appears in log file more and more, I scare that something is not good inside my system. Thank you so much.

```
    Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException 
in /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:3227
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13474): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#6 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11964): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13213): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13150): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#22 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9948): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8226): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#27 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8217): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8207): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2419): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(3286): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#35 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9948): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2366): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#40 /home/forge/default/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2350): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /home/forge/default/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 {main}
```

Comment: `AcessTokenMissMatch` happens when submitting forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, everytime you submit a post request a token is passed, `AcessTokenMismatch` error shows if the lifetime of that token expires (2 hours check your `config/session.php`). I suggest increasing the lifetime of the token.

Comment: thank you, It's still 120. Now I'll try to decrease to 1 and try to submit.

Comment: Why decrease? Increase the lifetime so that it won't expire quickly.

Comment: I want to make sure that is the reason, and It worked. Thank you so much